# It takes minutes to retrieve DB data

Tags: java

I created a REST API to handle basic rest functions for a search catalog application. The user can submit search queries via a POST and it will submit the queries to a MYSQL table. This gets processed and the results sent via a separate application via feeds within an hour later. 
My issue I am having is that a couple users can submit thousands of queries and the GET to retrieve these queries for the user, makes a simple request to the DB, but takes a long time to formulate the response. When the response was a simple list of single string queries it worked perfectly, within seconds. Now the response includes each query in its own json object with other meta data and a full array of objects is retrieved.I know it should not take this long so perhaps ideas on how to create the json might help.

```
            while (rs.next()){
                iquery = new Query();

                if (rs.isBeforeFirst() ) {    
                     System.out.println("No data"); 
                     qExists = "";
                } 
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));

                QueryList.add(rs.getString(2));
                query.setqueryRule(rs.getString(2));
                query.setqueryName(rs.getString(1));
                if(rs.getTimestamp(5) != null){
                    query.setqueryExpiration(rs.getTimestamp(5));
                }else {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }


                query.setqueryID(rs.getString(3));
                query.setqueryGUD(rs.getString(4));
                query.setqueryCreated(rs.getTimestamp(6));
                if(rs.getTimestamp(7) != null){
                    query.setqueryModified(rs.getTimestamp(7));
                }else {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }


                query.toString();
                QueryList.add(query);       


            }
            GreetingController.ResponseID = 1;
            return QueryList;
```

The class Query but it has all these different properties that I set as shown. But for some reason 50000 queries takes a long time as an example. I am showing below the example response a single query would like;

```
      "queries":[
     {
        "rule":"apple",
        "id":"y56473",
        "gid":"5bfufiddsd",
        "description":"apple's latest sneak peeks",
        "created":"2016-02-15T19:43:34Z",
        "modified":"2016-02-15T19:43:34Z",
        "expires":"2016-06-13T19:43:34Z"
     },
```

Any ideas appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**

MYSQL response time:

I ran the DB query and it was literally like 1-2 seconds.

```
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'f', 'ref', 'idx_', '4', 'const', '15727', 'Using where'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'd', 'const', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'const', '1', 'Using index'
```

Comment: Notwithstanding anything about the actual queries being run and *their* performance, getting rid of that `Thread.sleep` would speed it up 100ms per request at least...

Comment: That said, we are going to need to see if the bottleneck *could* be your database.  Take the output of one of those queries and place `EXPLAIN` in front of it.

Comment: Do you mean put EXPLAIN in front of the Select statement; sorry not a MYSQL fundi

Comment: You're not going to want to lace the explain in your working code.  Get a print off of it (you should be able to do this locally), ideally when you're ready to actually execute the query, and analyze its results inside of a MySQL query running tool.

Comment: Ok thanks will try and report back.Thanks for your response